# Condición en LEFT JOIN no activa condición "AND" después del ON

Tags: postgresql

tengo este ejemplo, tabla gastos, tabla gastos_depositos, tabla depositos (En depósitos tengo un boolean depositado_por_cliente true o false), tengo que sumar gastos que NO fueron depositados por clientes

Mi query está así

```
from gastos g
left join gastos_depositos gd on g.id = gd.id_gasto
left join depositos d on gd.id_deposito = d.id_deposito and d.depositado_por_cliente = false
```

PD: (no cargo la condición en el WHERE, por que existe gastos SIN DEPOSITOS, por ende, no traerá NADA)
Y me sigue sumando los montos, como que la condición en el left está obviando

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Si usas `LEFT JOIN` te traerá `NULL` en los datos que no hayan coincidencia, ¿no será un `INNER JOIN` lo que necesitas?

Comment: Nos mostras un ejemplo donde claramente se note que no esta usando el and?

Comment: Si, paso el query completo:select * from pulpo_despacho_schema.despachos_gastos dg 
 join pulpo_despacho_schema.despachos d on d.id_despacho = dg.id_despacho 
 left join pulpo_despacho_schema.gastos_depositos_sofia gds on gds.id_gasto_despacho = dg.id 
 left join pulpo_despacho_schema.depositos_sofia ds on gds.id_deposito = ds.id_deposito and ds.depositado_por_cliente = false
 where d.id_despacho = 44089

Comment: Inner JOIN no me va a funcionar, por que quiero traer gastos que NO fueron depositados por cliente, pero hay gastos que no tienen depositos, solo me va a traer gastos con depósitos, yo necesito, gastos, gastos con depósitos PERO NO FUERON DEPOSITADOS POR CLIENTE, osea, una condición al entrar en depósitos, no estoy logrando esa última parte

Answer (score 0):

Una consulta del tipo

```
     SELECT izquierda.id 
        FROM izquierda
        LEFT JOIN derecha ON 1 != 1
```

Traerá por definición todos los registros de la tabla izquierda. Mientras que otra consulta:

```
     SELECT izquierda.id 
        FROM izquierda
        LEFT JOIN derecha ON 1 = 1
     WHERE true = false
```

No traerá nada, también por definición.

Para ver lo que te está ocurriendo, pensemos en las siguientes dos tablas `gastos` y `depositos`
(bauticé la PK como `id_gasto` y `id_deposito` sólo para facilitar su distición. En tu caso se llaman  `id`, que es la convención correcta)

| id_gasto | monto_gasto |
| --- | --- |
| G101 | 500 |
| G102 | 400 |
| G103 | 100 |

y

| id_deposito | por_cliente |
| --- | --- |
| D28 | FALSE |
| D29 | TRUE |

Cuando existe una cuadratura entre un cierto gasto y un cierto depósito, ésta se refleja en la tabla `gastos_depositos`:

| id_gasto | id_deposito |
| --- | --- |
| G101 | D28 |
| G103 | D29 |

---

Si quieres obtener los gastos cuyo depósito no fue por cliente, y **también** los gastos sin un depósito relacionado, revisemos el resultado de tres variantes:

---

#### Consulta sin ninguna condición:

```
 SELECT * FROM gastos gs
     LEFT JOIN gastos_depositos dg ON gs.id_gasto=dg.id_gasto
     LEFT JOIN depositos dp ON dg.id_deposito=dp.id_deposito
```

| id_gasto | monto_gasto | id_deposito | por_cliente |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G101 | 500 | D28 | FALSE | ✔️ |
| G102 | 400 | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | ✔️ |
| G103 | 100 | D29 | TRUE | ✖️ falso negativo |

No sirve para excluir la tupla `[G103,D29]`

---

#### Condición en la cláusula `WHERE`

```
 SELECT * FROM gastos gs
     LEFT JOIN gastos_depositos dg ON gs.id_gasto=dg.id_gasto
     LEFT JOIN depositos dp ON dg.id_deposito=dp.id_deposito
 WHERE por_cliente = false
```

| id_gasto | monto_gasto | id_deposito | por_cliente |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G101 | 500 | D28 | FALSE | ✔️ |
| - | - | - | - | ✖️ falso positivo |
| - | - | - | - | ✔️ |

Quitará correctamente la tupla `[G103,D29]`, pero *excluirá incorrectamente   el gasto G102*

---

#### Condición en la cláusula `ON`  del segundo `LEFT JOIN`

```
 SELECT * FROM gastos gs
     LEFT JOIN gastos_depositos dg ON gs.id_gasto=dg.id_gasto
     LEFT JOIN depositos dp ON dg.id_deposito=dp.id_deposito AND dp.por_cliente = false
```

Excluirá el registro D29 *de la tabla depósitos*, pero **no de la tabla gastos**:

| id_gasto | monto_gasto | id_deposito | por_cliente |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G101 | 500 | D28 | FALSE | ✔️ |
| G102 | 400 | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | ✔️ |
| G103 | 100 | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | ✖️ falso negativo |

---

## Solución propuesta

```
 SELECT * FROM gastos gs
     LEFT JOIN gastos_depositos dg ON gs.id_gasto=dg.id_gasto
     LEFT JOIN depositos dp ON dg.id_deposito=dp.id_deposito
 WHERE (por_cliente = false OR por_cliente IS NULL)
```

| id_gasto | monto_gasto | id_deposito | por_cliente |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G101 | 500 | D28 | FALSE | ✔️ |
| G102 | 400 | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | <kbd>NULL</kbd> | ✔️ |
| - | - | - | - | ✔️ |